# How to modify javascript code on the fly in browser in debugging mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, browser, firebug

I want to use some IDE which allows me to change the javaScript code on the fly and run it in browser.
I don't think I can do this in Firebug.

Which IDE/software should I use for JavaScript development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do this in firebug console. Click on console and you can start typing. You can click on the bottom right red icon to expand the typing area.

Comment: Isn't there any other ide which I can use for javascript development? I mean even Eclipse is there but not as good as Firebug. Isn't there any more tools?

Comment: Firebug or chrome console would be the number 1 choices. Used by most developers. It can't get any more convenient. You see it as it's done. You don't need an IDE for this.

Comment: That's a very short answer. See more details bellow :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Sublime Web Inspector](http://sokolovstas.github.com/SublimeWebInspector/) looks like it could do what your after.

It supports:

- Breakpoints
- Console
- Interactivity
- Debugger
- Evaluating on call frame
- Live Reload

Comment: Seem like a nice alternative...only it also seem to be an abandoned project and very difficult to install. (No instructions!)